# ENOTEMPTY directory not empty, rmdir: npm-react-popper-tooltip

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, yarnpkg

I am not a frontend developer but sometimes I have to run some tasks like `yarn install && yarn build-dev`. Currently I am running just `yarn install` as shown below but I can not get it to work properly and have no clues on what is wrong or how to fix it:

```
▶ yarn install
yarn install v1.22.4
[1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "ENOTEMPTY: directory not empty, rmdir '/Users/reynierpm/Library/Caches/Yarn/v6/npm-react-popper-tooltip-2.10.1-e10875f31916297c694d64a677d6f8fa0a48b4d1-integrity/node_modules/react-popper-tooltip'".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/Users/reynierpm/dev/docker/web/yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
warning mini-css-extract-plugin@0.4.2: Invalid bin field for "mini-css-extract-plugin".
```

What I have tried so far?

- Google for some solutions
- a few SO post solutions
- Delete the content of the directory using `rm -rf`
- Clear yarn cache `yarn cache clean`

None of them worked. What could be wrong here?

I am using MacOS Catalina 10.15.4 and the command was run from iTerm2 using ZSH.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue but these options helped me

- Make sure you don't have file explore open on that folder
- Make sure you don't have `nodemon` running
- Make sure you don't have `live-server-extension` in your IDE (like visual studio) running
- Make sure you don't have any live process that is currently using your app directory

Comment: none of those bullet points worked for me :(